# how to build a xml response in twiml in ruby with comments

Tags: twilio

Xml response like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
    <!--my error message-->
<Reject/>
</Response>
```

enter code here:

currently i am using ruby to build response

```
xml.Response do |r|
     r.Reject
end.text
```

I need a comment before reject verb..Any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here.

[Twilio's Ruby helper library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby) is built on Builder (see [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/master/lib/twilio-ruby/twiml/response.rb)). Therefore, you can use the standard [Builder approach](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder):

```
xml.Response do |r|
  r.comment! "This is a comment!"
  r.Reject
end.text
```

This will generate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <!--This is a comment!-->
  <Reject/>
</Response>
```

Hope this helps!